# PHP Online Documentation Software

Tags: php, cms

I'm creating an Open Source software in PHP. I have set up a website and I want to make the documentation of the software.

I can't use WordPress for this, because it uses too much space for a simple task and there aren't any themes for documentation.

I need a documentation CMS like [Laravel's](http://laravel.com/docs) which is easy to manage and is somewhat like a blog, but looks like a documentation page.

Is there any softwares in PHP that does this job ? It would be much better if the software is wriiten in Laravel framework.

Answer (score 1):

[PongoCMS](http://pongocms.com/) might be for you. It is built on top of the Laravel framework and twitter's bootstrap. Note that I have never used this before so I can't honestly say how well it works. From the looks of it, it looks very easy to add pages and add content to those pages.

### Features:

- Multilingual website management
- WYSIWYG or HTML rich text-areas
- Blog management
- Multiple file uploads
- Auto thumbnail generator
- Front-end / back-end access level
- Google Analytics overview
- Granular cache management
- Password protected pages
- Per-page SEO optimization
- Sitemap management
- Database backup
- Open source
- Built on Laravel's framework and bootstrap
- Ability to make your own themes

From the looks of it, the only disadvantage is that it only comes with one theme and you would have to fool around with the default to make it to your liking.

Take a look at their [getting started](http://pongocms.com/getting-started) page on the requirements for pongo and how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: Don't click on the links in the above post, they are not what they say they are.

To answer the question, I would highly recommend [http://phpfui.com/InstaDoc](http://phpfui.com/?n=PHPFUI%5CInstaDoc) for this. Runs as a PHP script right on your server. Will produce static files if you need them for high volume sites. Easy to install and set up. Maybe 2 minutes to usable documentation for your code and all the third party code you use in your app.